# vaadin 6.5.7 - How to filter multiple values in a container using

Tags: vaadin

I'm looking for a solution where I would like to filter my container with multiple values
using logical OR.

For instance, I would like to filter my value and get the result where value == "A" or "B"

This piece of code works when I only have 1 value :

```
private void applyTextFilters(List<String> filters)
{
    unselectAllItems();

    IndexedContainer container = (IndexedContainer) valuesTable.getContainerDataSource();
    container.removeContainerFilters(Columns.SEARCH.id());

    for (String filter : filters) {
        container.addContainerFilter(Columns.SEARCH.id(), filter, true, false);
    }

    clinicalValuesGraph.refreshGraph(container, getLabel("clinicalvalues.graph.caption"));
    // if it is the case ...
    //toggleEmptyResultNotification();
    handleView(viewMode);
}
```

What am I missing? Again, if I have 2 filters ("A","B") in my code, none of the results show but if I pass "A", it works.

To follow with my question...

Using 6.5.7, I need to filter my container with 2 criterias as in search names like "patrick" OR "john".

I've inspected the code and this is where I would need to modify a method (which is protected) :

```
protected boolean passesFilters(Object itemId) {
    IndexedContainerItem item = new IndexedContainerItem(itemId);
    if (filters == null) {
        return true;
    }
    final Iterator<Filter> i = filters.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        final Filter f = i.next();
        if (!f.passesFilter(item)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**TO THIS :**

```
protected boolean passesFilters(Object itemId) {
    IndexedContainerItem item = new IndexedContainerItem(itemId);
    if (filters == null) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean previouslyPassedFilter = false;
    boolean PassesFilter = true;

    final Iterator<Filter> i = filters.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        final Filter f = i.next();
        if (!f.passesFilter(item) && !previouslyPassedFilter) {
            passesFilter = false;
        } else {
            previouslyPassedFilter = true;
        }
    }
    return passesFilter ;
}
```

How would that be done without having to rewrite all of these classes (IndexedContainer, IndexContainerItem...) ?

Comment: I think you would need to switch to Vaadin 6.6+. It ships with filters located in `com.vaadin.data.util.filter`, among which there is `Or`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I specifically said that I need to do it with 6.5.7...